# Link my page3.html to certain location of the page

Tags: html

How do I load a page and get it to open at a certain location of the page?
I have a page that got links that links to certain location of the page by using ID's. When I am on the page and clicks on those link it takes me to the certain location which is fine.

**BUT the problem is here:** 
when I only search for on www.page3.html this takes me to the top of the page and I have to scroll down to read the page3.html. I want this page to open at that certain location I have indicated with an ID. "#3".

How can I do that?
I tried to rename the html file as page3.html#3, but of course that did not work.

`<ul>` 
`<a href="page1.html#1">1</a></li>`
`<li><a href="page2.html#2">2</a></li>`
`<li><a href="page3.html#3">3</a></li>`
`</ul>`

Comment: You're on the right track. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html/254/anchors-and-hyperlinks/1076/link-to-an-anchor#t=201608121030407646603

Comment: Try using ids that start with a letter, not a digit. (Although the latter is valid in HTML5, I would not bet on all browsers supporting that correctly in anchor links.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That lets me jump to the specific location of the page yes. I have successfully done that. But my issue is not there. My issue is that. I have several of pages example: page1.html, page2.html etc which links to the certain locations with help of ID. When I click on those links it links me there. BUT when I type www.mypage/ipage3.html it will link to the top of the page, but not the section I added as div id tag.

Answer (score 0):

still name your pages page1.html page2.html etc

give a div the ID you want to navigate to on that page

```
<div id="three">go here</div>
```

then your a tag would be

```
<a href="page.html#three">Link</a>
```